# how mac closes the apps on shutdown process?

Tags: apache-flex, macos, shutdown

i need to know how the Mac OS closes the running application when shutdown is pressed,

i am working in flex and want to capture that event (if that is an event or else) to stop closing my app state away.

i need my app to ask for close the app YES or NO. on yes resumes the shutdown and on no do not close the app and shutdown processes it also stopped.

need help

regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of anything Mac specific.

But can you add an event listener on the WindowedApplication for the [close](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/WindowedApplication.html#event%3aclose) event?  Also look at the [closing](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/WindowedApplication.html#event%3aclosing) event to do something before the app window closes.

I assume closing the main app window is the same as exiting the application.

Comment: closing and exiting is not same there is a little difference, anyhow i just need any thing that let me shutdown the mac through my flex app and before this listen that mac ask the app to close down when mac is going to shutdown, simply can i find that the exiting call is sent by a shutdown process of mac?

Comment: @moon You want to shut down your Mac from the Flex application? That is not clear to me from the original question.  I'm pretty sure that such a thing is impossible w/ just Flex.  You'll want to look into using NativeProcess if you want to do that; and even then I have no idea what type of APIs Mac exposes to shut down the computer.

Comment: @Flextras Now you got my point i am also come to same opinion as yours and now trying to use nativeProcess in flex thanks for your comments